# Rails association - what controller code gets executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a change to some controller code.  But, I don't understand where to put it.

I have the following in a new Contact form:

```
    <%= f.association :location, :label_method => :name, :label => 'Location:' %>
```

I assumed that code would execute the index code in the location's controller.

But, I just deleted all of the code in the location index and the Contact form with the association to Location still has data in it.

I want the following code to execute at the Contact association stmt, but I don't know where to put it:

```
@locations = Location.ordered_by_ancestry_and(:name).map { |l| ["  " * l.depth + l.name, l.id] }
```

UPDATE1

This is the development.log

```
Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
Location Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY (case when locations.ancestry is null then 0 else 1 end), locations.ancestry, name
```

UPDATE2

I changed the ContactsController#new to this for testing:

```
 # GET /contacts/new
 # GET /contacts/new.json
 def new
   @locations = Location.first
```

And I still got all the locations in the select box.

Comment: Controller code will only get executed when that controller action is triggered, and that only happens when a link is followed or a form is posted. What do you mean "execute the index code"? Are you following what `log/development.log` says about what controller methods are being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleFormFor `association` helper method will generate a list (as a select list by default, but can be modified to radio or checkbox list) that acts as a nested attribute for that association.  When submitted this field will be passed to the same controller action as the parent form - in this case the `ContactsController#create` action.

As far as your customized list of locations, you can pass this as a `collection` option to the `association` method:

```
<%= f.association :location, :collection => @locations, :label_method => :name, :label => 'Location:' %>
```

The actual place to build this `@locations` list would be in any action that may need to access it - that includes `new` and `edit`, as well as `create` and `update` (in case an error prevents your form from submitting).  You can use a `before_filter` to eliminate any duplication.

The code may look something like:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_locations, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update]

  #... actions go here

  private
  def load_locations
    @locations = Location.ordered_by_ancestry_and(:name).map do |l| 
      ["  " * l.depth + l.name, l.id]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I put this in the `ContactsController#create` and I still got a list of locations.  `  # POST /contacts
  # POST /contacts.json
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @locations = nil`

Comment: Updated to explain this better.